# I don't know what I'm doing! Please Help?

Tags: syntax

What is wrong with this template code??

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="featureinfo" limit="1" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}
{sn_header_news}
<div id="mainb">
    <div id="mainc">
        <div id="cimg"><img src="/images/made/images/made/Header-NewsMedia.jpg" alt="Latest News" width="483" height="210" /></div>
        <div id="contbody"><div id="column">
        {sn_newsmedia}
        {embed="index/.colnews"}
        {embed="index/.colpromem"}
            </div>
        <div id="contentc">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
            {if news_image}{exp:ce_img:single src="{news_image}" alt="{title}" width="240" height="160" crop="yes" class="img1"}{/if}
            <h6>Posted: {entry_date format="%l, %j%S %M %Y"}</h6>
            {news_outline}
            </ul>{/if}
            {if news_file}
            <div class="box">
            <h2>Download Related Info</h2>
            <ul>{exp:jco_getfileinfo filename="{news_file}"}
            <li><a href="{news_file}" title="Download {news_filename}" target="_blank">{news_filename}</a> &nbsp; <span style="text-transform:uppercase; font-size:12px; color:#999">({file_extension} - {file_size})</span></li>
            {/exp:jco_getfileinfo}
            </ul>
            </div>{/if}
        </div></div>
    </div>
{sn_footer}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

When I view the rendered template i get this error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in /home/coiorg/public_html/splodge/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(679) : eval()'d code on line 495

My apologies in advance for being a nuisance!

Answer (score 4):

Error you are getting is comes only when your {if} statement criteria is not fulfilled. In your case, You have close 1 {/if} without starting any {if} condition. Try this code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="featureinfo" limit="1" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}
{sn_header_news}
<div id="mainb">
    <div id="mainc">
        <div id="cimg">
            <img src="/images/made/images/made/Header-NewsMedia.jpg" alt="Latest News" width="483" height="210" />
        </div>
        <div id="contbody">
            <div id="column">
                {sn_newsmedia}
                {embed="index/.colnews"}
                {embed="index/.colpromem"}
            </div>
            <div id="contentc">
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                {if news_image}{exp:ce_img:single src="{news_image}" alt="{title}" width="240" height="160" crop="yes" class="img1"}{/if}
                <h6>Posted: {entry_date format="%l, %j%S %M %Y"}</h6>
                {news_outline}
                {if news_file}
                <div class="box">
                    <h2>Download Related Info</h2>
                    <ul>
                        {exp:jco_getfileinfo filename="{news_file}"}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{news_file}" title="Download {news_filename}" target="_blank">{news_filename}</a> &nbsp; 
                            <span style="text-transform:uppercase; font-size:12px; color:#999">({file_extension} - {file_size})</span>
                        </li>
                        {/exp:jco_getfileinfo}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {/if}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{sn_footer}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```